# cassandra data model for web logging

Tags: cassandra

Been playing around with Cassandra and I am trying to evaluate what would be the best data model for storing things like views or hits for unique page id's? Would it best to have a single column family per pageid, or 1 Super-column (logs) with columns pageid? Each page has a unique id, then would like to store date and some other metrics on the view.

I am just not sure which solution handles better scalability, lots of column family OR 1 giant super-column?

page-92838 { date:sept 2, browser:IE }
page-22939 { date:sept 2, browser:IE5 }

OR

logs {
   page-92838 {
      date:sept 2,
      browser:IE
   }
   page-22939 {
      date:sept 2,
      browser:IE5
   }
}

And secondly, how to handle lots of different date: entries for page-92838?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cassandra, it is best to start with what queries you need to do, and model your schema to support those queries.

Assuming you want to query hits on a page, and hits by browser, you can have a [counter column](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters) for each page like,

```
stats { #cf 
    page-id { #key
        hits : # counter column for hits
        browser-ie : #counts of views with ie
        browser-firefox : ....
    }
}
```

If you need to do time based queries, look at how twitters [rainbird denormalizes](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2181119) as it writes to cassandra.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this column setup, I assume stats is a super-column?

Comment: interesting, so, stats is a normal column family? Would the data model look like this (using the cli-monitor):  stats['399485']['hits'] = 4;  
stats['129495']['hits'] = 56;

Comment: so, using that data model, for users I would have something like:

    userstats['bob'][timeuuid] = 399485; #pageid    
    userstats['bob'][timeuuid] = 455212; #another pageid    
    userstats['sally'][timeuuid] = 129495; #pageid

Comment: Is it a good practise to store this as columns? IMO this would lead to huge rows, assuming that the row-key is "page-12345". Would it be recommendable to use different rows for each pageid where the row-key contains an indicator of the time? example: stats['page-1-alltime]=100 ; stats['page-1-2011]=90; stats['page-1-2011-11]=20; stats['page-1-2011-11-21]=5  That's how I understood the rainbird denormalization. advantage i see is that you get better distribution of rows accross the cluster

Comment: @Christoph, changed the #column to #key, that was a typo

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a column-family per pageid.

One solution is to have a row for each page, keyed on the pageid.

You could then have a column for each page-view or hit, keyed and sorted on time-UUID (assuming having the views in time-sorted order would be useful) or other unique, always-increasing counter. Note that all Cassandra columns are time-stamped anyway, so you would have a precise timestamp 'for free' regardless of what other time- or date- stamps you use. Using a precise time-UUID as the key also solves the problem of storing many hits on the same date.

The value of each column could then be a textual value or JSON document containing any other metadata you want to store (such as browser).

```
page-12345 -> {timeuuid1:metadata1}{timeuuid2:metadata2}{timeuuid3:metadata3}...
page-12346 -> ...
```