# Data model for web page beacons

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'd like to store millions of web page beacons in Cassandra, each of which look roughly like the following JSON:

```
'{
  "uri": "http://foo.com/bar/index.html",
  "metric1": 74,
  "metric2": 123,
  "conntime": "2011-12-30T13:43:34",
  "city": "CAMBRIDGE",
  "state": "MA",
  "ua": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2",
  "plat": "Win32"
 }'
```

Where the string contains the the URI, a number of metrics, followed by geo/browser/platform data.  As you can imagine, there will be a smaller number of distinct
URIs/UAs/Plats/Cities/States, while the value of each metric will vary extensively.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627050/cassandra-data-model-for-web-logging) and [this](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2181119), but my queries will look more like the following, which don't seem to be a good fit for counters:

- What is the median 'metric1' for each ('ua','plat','state','city')?
- What is the 95th percentile of 'metric2' at 'conntime' "2011-12-30T13:43:34"?

Is it possible (and wise) to denormalize my data to be counters?  Or is there a better way to model the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether the sets of indicators and of query dimensions are well defined or not (i.e., you only need mean, median for each 'ua', 'state'. Both sets might be quite long, yet finite)

Additive indicators might be stored in counter columns (if you have count & sum, you can always calculate mean):

```
CF[event.ua].metric1_sum += event.metric1;
CF[event.ua].metric1_count++;
CF[event.state].metric1_sum += event.metric1;
CF[event.state].metric1_count++;
....
```

To calculate median and percentiles, I'd suggest to create super-column with counter subcolumns. Metric values are subcolumn names, and **count of** events are subcolumn values:

```
CF[event.ua].metric1_values[event.metric1]++;
CF[event.state].metric1_values[event.metric1]++;
...
```

In case if the amount of distinct metric values will be too high, it would be probably possible to round up metric values without serious infelicity.

Other indicator kinds might require other optimisations.

And still, I'd suggest to store individual events in denormalized form, similar to mentioned JSON. Cassandra is very fast in writing data. And having raw data would allow you to calculate history values of additional indicators by running Map/Reduce on full data set.

Comment: This makes sense.  If I understand correctly, to calculate the median, the data would look roughly like the following:  `CF["http://foo.com/bar/index.html"."Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"].metric1_74["http://foo.com/bar/index.html".metric1]++;`  Or, since most of the data analysis will be done offline (say, once an hour), is it better just to store the raw JSON and *only* do Map/Reduce?